# Google Maps Api V3 - StreetView enableCloseButton

Tags: google-maps-api-3

in the current Version of Google Maps Api v3 (using latest 3.x) the option "enableCloseButton" for StreetView has no effect, the close button remains hidden as by default, while others like "fullscreenControl", "linksControl" etc. work as expected.

The corresponding documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-controls?hl=en

It can be tested with the JSFiddle provided on the same page.

Slightly changed code:

```
  function initPano() {
    // Note: constructed panorama objects have visible: true
    // set by default.
    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('map'), {
          position: {lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326},
          addressControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
          },
          linksControl: false,
          panControl: false,
          fullscreenControl: false,
          enableCloseButton: true
    });
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f0490gnp/

Setting "enableCloseButton" to "true" in the example has no effect, the "x" is not showing in the upper right corner. 
Is this a known bug, is there any workaround for this, or am I missing something? Currently when dragging the 'pegman' onto the map it is not possible to switch back to map view.

Thanks for any hint.

(Update: fixed jsfiddle link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "close button" is the right arrow that appears to the left of the address (when `enableCloseButton:true`, but not when `enableCloseButton:false`.  If clicked, the panorama turns grey in the fiddle.

[image: image with enableCloseButton=true]
[image: image with enableCloseButton=false]